# how would i check a game board for 4 pieces the same in a row? (android)

Tags: android, algorithm, gridview, arraylist

I'm just starting to build an android board game.

My game board is a 5x5 `GridView` and I'm storing all of the squares of this grid in an `ArrayList`, too.

Each square has a public value, representing what the user decided to place on that square. I want to check these values to see if there are 4 or 5 the same in a row. If this is the case then those squares clear out - like jewel games where you make groups of the same color.

Can anyone give me a pointer for the best way to go about checking this? I was looping through the `ArrayList` for each row but that's about as far as I got so far!

Comment: Show us some code of what you've done so far and explain what doesn't work. Also, please format your post before sending it.

Comment: It's not that what I've done so far doesn't work, there is barely anything to show - it's not started yet.  I was just asking if people could give me a pointer as to how to go about this.  Which they have done.

Answer (score 2):

Just check the values of the rows or columns related to last changed square. You don't need go through all squares... if the game doesn't have any feature other than you specified above.